# How to use trackBy on AsyncPipe with images rendering, it re- renders page every time?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angularjs-track-by

My question is how to use trackby on Async pipe with images rendering under it.

I have done following.
in html

```html
<div *ngFor="let friend of friends$ | async;trackBy:trackByFn">
  <img [src]="friend.image">
</div>
```

and in my component.ts

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    if(!item) return null;
    return item && item.id; // or item.id
}
```

Now problem is that i have a timer of 2 minutes after that i push new elements to friend$ observable using next statement

```
 this.friends$.next(data);
```

everytime i do that i can see request for all images. And blink effect on every image why?
i am using track by to do not rerender dom elements.

Comment: try to change your `trackByFn` to return all to true and see if it renders back

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a whole new dataset everytime. Try pushing only a new value to your observable, and treat your subject like an array :

friends$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

```
add(value) {
  this.friends$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(items => {
    items.push(value);
    this.friends.next(items);
  });
}
```

This should automatically resolve your issue, without the need of a track by function.